# Can I verify an xml signature in Silverlight?

Tags: xml, silverlight, digital-signature

I have a requirement to validate an XML signature from within Silverlight. In full .NET, there are XmlDocument and SignedXml objects which can be used to perform this task. Seeing as these do not exist in Silverlight, is there another way to do this, perhaps using XDocument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind third-party solutions, one of the options is [XMLBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-xml.php) package of our SecureBlackbox. It supports XMLEnc, XMLDSig and XAdES and includes Silverlight assemblies.